# How to set the virtual user to get the data from file and hit at same time in one iteration VSTS @ Load Test

Tags: load-testing

Scenario:
I create the web test for creating new user with registration form.
Then I create 30 records of new user with different data at access/excel file
Now I want to create the Virtual users total 30. each virtual
Now I data bind the access/excel file with web test.
I want to run all these 30 users simultaneously and can get the data from access/excel file on same time and complete the scenario in one iteration.
how I can do it?

Regards,
Tufail
tufailfifa99@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have a CSV with usernames and passwords.
2. Add a datasource to your web test.
3. Go to the properties of your datasource and select the appropriate access method (Random, Sequential or Unique). More information about these access methods can be found here...
   [Access Methods] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.webtesting.databindingaccessmethod%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

If all else fails you may have to create your own request plugin.